# How to pass item.src to a template in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, template

I have a Jinja2 template and I want to pass args to it from my `vars/main.yml`.

For each set of vars, I need to generate a separate file on the remote server.

My `vars/main.yml` has the following structure:

```
List:
  - { src: [
        classPath1: xxx,
        classPath2: xxx, 
        contxtHost: xxx,
        logDir: xxx, 
        contxtRegion: xxx,
        .... 
        ],
      dest: xxxx 
    }
  - { src: [
        xxxx
        ], 
      dest: xxxx 
    }
```

in my playbook task is defined as below:

```
  - name: testing templates 
    template: "src=templates/sampletest.j2 
               dest=/path/in/Server/{{ item.dest }}
               owner=app 
               group=app 
               mode=0644"
    with_items: '{{ List }}'
```

How do I pass `item.src` to my template?

Note: I am trying to generate multiple files based on each set of vars `item.src` and file name is `item.dest` using `with_items`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reference them in the `templates/sampletest.j2`, for example:

```
# start of the template
classPath1 is {{ item.src[0].classPath1 }}
classPath2 is {{ item.src[1].classPath2 }}
contxtHost is {{ item.src[2].contxtHost }}
...
# end of the template
```

For each item on the `List` the template will be parsed and saved to a file defined in `dest`.

---

Now, the problem is that your `vars/main.yml` file defines `src` as a list (square brackets) of dictionaries, each containing a single key-value pair (with the key named differently in each item on the list), so:

- first, you need to reference the list item by its order (e.g. `src[1]`)
- then, you need to reference the key which is defined in that particular item (e.g. `classPath2` for and only for `src[1]`).